# Хранение сессии в Mysql

Tags: сессия, php, mysql

Читал, что хранить сессию в Mysql выгодна, когда сайт работает на нескольких серверах. Я вот задался таким вопросом, а какие вообще есть ещё плюсы и минусы хранения сессии в БД. Может повышается безопасность, так как злоумышленнику становиться до неё сложнее добраться?

Answer (score 1):

Есть ситуации когда сессию неоходимо хранить в базе данных, а есть ситуации когда это излишне, всё зависит от решаемых задач. Однако, храня сессии в БД следует задуматься о том что сессии придется очищать.

Добраться до сессии хранящейся в БД легче, чем когда она хранится на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт настолько огромен, что для его работы требуется более одного сервера, скорее всего для его работы действительно может потребоваться хранить данные в БД, с другой стороны, если он настолько огромен, может стоит задуматься о выборе другой СУБД? мускул идеально подходит для средних проектов. Для сайтов типа вконтакте mysql не подойдет, хотя бы ввиду ограничения размера mysql. Хотя я могу ошибаться. 
Я храню сессии авторизации в БД, но они предназначены для контроля присутствия / отсутствия пользователя на сайте, методом проверки времени записи сессии, нужно ли Вам это делать - зависит только от Ваших потребностей (это если проект все таки не "вконтакте").

Comment: Какие ограничения MySQL вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ограничение размера. 1 ГБ для MySQL, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Ozim, вы с чего это взяли то?

Answer (score 0):

И там и там есть свои плюсы и минусы, есть еще способ хранить их в мемкеше :). На самом деле, хранение сесий в базе данных интересно тем что можна выгнять всех пользоватеелй с сервера одним кликом мышки . Это я так, юмор :).